# play MIDI (*.mid) files in firefox

Tags: freebsd, firefox, midi

Many of the (German) Wikipedia articles about bands contain short music samples, like the one for [Emerson, Lake & Palmer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerson,_Lake_and_Palmer). (Look for the speaker symbols).
Firefox then asks for an application to run the *.mid file. I tried selecting mplayer but that remained silent. Then I downloaded the *.mid file and tried to play it using mplayer's CLI, to no avail.
Next, I installed the `audio/playmidi` port. Trying to play with `playmidi` results in an `open /dev/sequencer: No such file or directory` error.

How can I play *.mid files?

Answer (score -1):

- alsa (CLI) requires a synth: 
  `aplaymidi file.mid`
- Firefox with plugin VLC: 

  It's tricky, may require fluid synth.
- Firefox with plugin totem: 
  no-embedding.
- timidity (CLI) or timidity++ (GUI)
  sure thing; sounds great with the fluid synth gm sound-font, then some configuration.